# Translate CRC alrgorythm from C to PHP

Tags: php, c, crc

### **SOLVED**

I have the following code on C and I have to write it on PHP

```
const U16 crc_table[16] = {
    0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5, 0x60c6, 0x70e7,
    0x8108, 0x9129, 0xa14a, 0xb16b, 0xc18c, 0xd1ad, 0xe1ce, 0xf1ef
};

U16 CalculateCrc(char *data, U32 len) {
    U32 i;
    U16 crc = 0;

    while (len--) {
        i = (crc >> 12) ^ (*data >> 4);
        crc = crc_table[i & 0x0F] ^ (crc << 4);
        i = (crc >> 12) ^ (*data >> 0);
        crc = crc_table[i & 0x0F] ^ (crc << 4);
        data++;
    }
    return (crc & 0xFFFF);
}
```

In a basic logic translation, I did this so far:

```
public function crc($data){

        $i = 0;
        $crc = 0;

        /* @var $crc_table array */
        $crc_table = array
            (
                0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5, 0x60c6, 0x70e7,
                0x8108, 0x9129, 0xa14a, 0xb16b, 0xc18c, 0xd1ad, 0xe1ce, 0xf1ef
            );

        for($a = 0; $a < strlen($data); $a++){
            $i = (($crc >> 12) ^ ($data[$a] >> 4));
            $crc = ($crc_table[$i & 0x0F] ^ ($crc << 4));
            $i = (($crc >> 12) ^ $data[$a]);
            $crc = ($crc_table[$i & 0x0F] ^ ($crc << 4));
        }



        return ($crc & 0xFFFF);

    }
```

The results are not matching by no means and I'm no expert on this kind of thing. Any suggestion?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks "squeamish ossifrage"!
Based on your help, I'm using to this function now:

```
private function crc($data){

        $i = 0;
        $crc = 0;

        $crc_table = array
            (
                0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5, 0x60c6, 0x70e7,
                0x8108, 0x9129, 0xa14a, 0xb16b, 0xc18c, 0xd1ad, 0xe1ce, 0xf1ef
            );

        $data = hex2bin($data);
        $l = 0;
        while($l < strlen($data)){

            $byte = $data[$l];
            $i = (($crc >> 12) ^ (ord($byte) >> 4));
            $crc = ($crc_table[$i & 0x0F] ^ ($crc << 4));
            $i = (($crc >> 12) ^ (ord($byte) >> 4));
            $crc = ($crc_table[$i & 0x0F] ^ ($crc << 4));
            $l++;
        }

        return ($crc & 0xFFFF);

    }
```

I'm testing it with "Hello world" as hex "48656C6C6F20776F726C64".
On C I get 37278 and on php function above 56062.

Any clues now?

---

EDIT

Ok, my bad...the problem was already solved but I have confused myself after so many tests.

This is my first version of the code with the suggested correction by "squeamish ossifrage":

```
$byte = $data[$l];
$i = (($crc >> 12) ^ (ord($byte) >> 4));
$crc = ($crc_table[$i & 0x0F] ^ ($crc << 4));
$i = (($crc >> 12) ^ **ord($byte));**
$crc = ($crc_table[$i & 0x0F] ^ ($crc << 4));
$l++;
```

Thanks!

Comment: don't forget that php's ints are always 32bit or 64bit internally. bit overflows that can occur with a 16bit C int won't happen in php because there's plenty of "extra" bits to hold that overflow.

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in CRC computation? http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php

Comment: @EricJ. Yes, but I can't because I must run in compatibility with a the C algorithm, which I can't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you're computing XOR products of integers and string variables:

```
$i = (($crc >> 12) ^ ($data[$a] >> 4));
```

Here `$data[$a]` is a substring of the input data. You should use `ord()` to convert this to an integer:

```
$i = (($crc >> 12) ^ (ord($data[$a]) >> 4));
```

(**Edit:** With this change to your PHP code, the string `Hello, world!` hashes to 31454 in both functions.)

Comment: Nice! If my input is a 16 base string and I replace (ord($data[$a]) for intval($data[$a].$data[$a++],16) it should work, right?

Comment: No, that won't work. Did you mean `$data[$a].$data[$a+1]` (followed by `$a += 2`)? I expect `hex2bin()` would be a faster way of converting hexadecimal data to binary.

Comment: Yes, I mean it. Good, I'll try it with hex2bin! Thanks.

Comment: Just edited the quesiton based on your help. Glad if you could take a second look at this.